# Test data not visible by Dynamic SOQL

Tags: unit-test, dynamic-soql, aura-enabled

I have an seemingly simple aura enabled class for agreement lookup which returns maximum 8 records using dynamic SOQL. This class works fine from UI perspective. No issues so far while testing.
My only problem is getting the test class to pass by returning 8 rows from apex controller class.  While running test class, Assertion fails by returning 0 rows -
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 8, Actual: 0

Not sure what am I missing here. Please suggest.

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<sObject> fetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, String extraQueryCondition, String ObjectName, String fieldNames) {
    
        String searchKey = '%' + searchKeyWord + '%';
        List<sObject> returnList = new List <sObject> ();
        String sQuery = ' ';
        
        sQuery =  'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.Name FROM ' + ObjectName + 
           ' WHERE (Name LIKE :searchKey ' + extraQueryCondition + ') ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 8';
        
        List<sObject> listOfRecords = Database.query(sQuery);
        system.debug('listOfRecords =' + listOfRecords);    // returns 0 
        
        for (sObject obj: listOfRecords) {
            returnList.add(obj);
        }
        
        return returnList;
    }

}
```

**Following is corresponding test class  -**

---

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class CustomLookupController_Test {

    
    @testSetup 
     public static void create10Agreements() {
        List<Agreement__c> testAgreements = new List<Agreement__c>();
        for(Integer i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            Agreement__c a = APTS_TestDataFactory.create_NDA_Agreement_For_Plan_Agreement_Data();
            a.Name = 'test Agreement '+ i;
            testAgreements.add(a);
         }  
        insert testAgreements;
    }


    public static TestMethod void testAgreementFetchLookUpValues10(){

        Test.startTest();
        create10Agreements();  // works fine till this point 

        List<Agreement__c> agreements1 = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.Name from Agreement__c limit 10 ];
        system.debug('Size of agreements1 :' + agreements1.size());  // returns 10 
        
        List<Agreement__c> agreements = CustomLookupController.fetchLookUpValues('test Agreement', '', 'Agreement__c', 'Name');
        system.debug('Size of agreements :' + agreements.size());
        Test.stopTest();
       
        // Expecting 8 since there is a limit of 8 returned from the query.
        System.assertEquals(8, agreements.size());   //System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 8, Actual: 0
        
    }    
    
}
```

Comment: without seeing CustomLookupController.fetchLookupValues it will be hard to know the answer here. Your test data probably doesn't match what the controller expects

Comment: Yes i have already put the method CustomLookupController.fetchLookupValues . I missed to paste the 1st line - ```public with sharing class CustomLookupController { ```

Comment: N.B. the `@testSetup` method runs automatically  when the testmethod starts so no need to explicitly invoked `create10Agreements`

Comment: You are right, please discard that. i added that later while pasting here.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update with the solution.
There was a trigger which was causing to change the agreement Name to some other value. Because of this, the select query was not able to search with the given name-  'test Agreement'. Glad we found the root cause.